# How can Fody be used to weave compiled dll's without using msbuild?

Tags: c#, aop, fody

I understand that by default Fody weaves assemblies as a post-build step in Visual Studio.

However I have a custom tool that directly compiles projects using csc.exe (Roslyn compiler). Is it possible to run Fody as an executable/service instead of a post-build step?

Something like this: `fody.exe target.dll fody_settings.xml`

Comment: We needed this exact feature and developped https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fody.StandAlone/ Feel free to use it and please report any bugs that you find :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

- write an exe.
- In that exe reference the fody dll that is contained in the nuget
- use this class and pass in the required properties https://github.com/Fody/Fody/blob/master/FodyIsolated/InnerWeaver.cs
- you can see a use of this class here https://github.com/Fody/Fody/blob/master/Fody/Processor.cs#L139 note that in a console app you can ignore the remoting usage

Disclaimer: while these classes are public this is not considered an exposed API. So in minor version releases these classes may change.